# php программирование

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

Выучил основы **php**, **html**, **css**, **javascript (jquery)**, но не знаю как это все запомнить. Не хватает практики. Смотрю видеоуроки, читаю литературу, вроде все понятно, но сажусь что то писать и ничего толком не могу вспомнить. Подскажите, как лучше набивать руку в программировании.

Comment: Набирать практику, очевидно :) Делать, подглядывая в книжки, со временем выучится

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы научиться ездить на велосипеде...ничего лучше чем как можно чаще ездить на этом самом велосипеде, еще не придумали...(сколько не читай не смотри видео, пока сам не поедешь не научишься)...Тоже самое в любой области....(Например у поваров - первый блин комом ....хорошими поварами сразу не становятся)....главное интерес к своему делу...и труд..труд и труд!

В программирование тоже самое...пиши ..пиши и пиши ....чем больше пишешь тем больше получается и больше опыта....Пиши проект для себя...пиши на заказ...пиши для интереса..(если есть свои идеи - пиши их..если нет то пиши чужие....можешь за деньги а можешь и просто так..)

> но сажусь чтото писать и ничего толком не могу вспомнить

Читай 2 страницы киниги и сразу делай...думаю за 10-15 мин не успеешь забыть, а вообще если ты так быстро забываешь(то наверно тебе просто не интересно)и стоит задуматься твое ли это вообще направление...

Comment: Вот наоборот, как раз таки очень интересно. Я не то чтобы все забываю, основы все помню, а узкого профиля команды забываются. Но я так понял, что чем больше практиковаться, тем оно само будет запоминаться. Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 1):

лучше я думаю углубиться в какую нибудь одну сферу. определитесь, что для вас важней или легче, или что вам нравиться. если вы учите все это для того, чтобы зарабатывать деньги - изучите вакансии в вашем регионе и на основе этого сделайте выбор. обычно если начинают учить, то не берутся за все сразу, да и такие специалисты чаще всего не требуются.  нравиться создавать? любите математику? изучайте php и идите дальше в этом направлении. любите рисовать? творческий человек? изучайте html и css. на практике javascript используется не так часто, разве что для различных кредитных калькуляторов, да и для всяких украшательств, если вам этого достаточно - учите базовый уровень. а так конечно изучайте программирование, больше практикуйтесь, читайте книжки и смотрите видеоролики, сидите на тематических форумах. удачи!

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо

Comment: javascript явно недооценён)

Answer (score 1):

Судя по описанию проблемы, у Вас неверный подход. Практика должна содержаться уже в самом процессе обучения и быть неразрывной с ним. Для того чтобы информация не проносилась мимо ушей, Вы должны воспроизводить усвоенное, решать тестовые задания. **Просто смотреть и читать недостаточно**.

По каким курсам Вы занимались? Всё перечисленное Вами — достаточно распространённые вещи, для них наличествуют качественные материалы с **активными методами обучения**, чьи преимущества признаются исследованиями экспертов в педагогике.

Что бы я, вероятнее всего, делал на Вашем месте. Сначала искал бы материалы для новичков, по которым набираются положительные отзывы и оценки от профильных специалистов. Хотя бы на этом сайте по поисковым запросам вроде «материалы CSS», «литература по JavaScript». После нахождения открыл бы данные материалы сначала и пытался б *а)* воспроизводить коды у себя на компьютере, *б)* решать предлагаемые задания. Т. к. Вы уже знакомы с основами, Вам будет проще, чем новичкам, процесс пойдёт быстрее.

Активное обучение способствует долговременному запоминанию.

Ну и раз уж Вы на Stack Overflow, после того, как почувствуете себя в тематике более-менее уверенно, попробуйте набивать руку здесь, отвечая на вопросы, среди которых ежедневно попадается множество несложных с точки зрения опытных программистов. Если дружите с английским — на https://stackoverflow.com/ вопросов ещё больше. Полезно обращать внимание и на неотвеченные старые вопросы — в основном, они сложнее, но зато нет гонок на скорость, отнюдь не воспрещается основательно подумать.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Это нормально! А что вы хотели, то что вы основы выучили это лишь 5% пути, остальное практика практика практика! В основном ступор перед задачей возникает из-за того что ставите сразу сложные задачи, не стоит спешить! Возьмите и попробуйте сделать простенький сайт и не один, а так 10-ок сайтов! Затем десяток более сложных сайтов, а там и до интернет магазов не далеко! ЭТО ЕДИНСТВЕННЫЙ СПОСОБ, другого еще не придумали!

Запоминать специально ничего не нужно, это так не работает, тут главное руку набить! И еще, когда вы начнете реальную практику, вы поймете что на самом деле вы много еще всего не знаете) УДАЧИ!

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос. что подразумеваете под словом простенький сайт? обычную страничку труда у меня не составляет создать.

Comment: Ну по сложности они разделяются так: 
1. Сайт Визитка
2. Корпоративный сайт
3. Блог
4. Интернет магазин
Это вы так говорите, что у вас не составить труда создать))), на самом деле вы заблуждаетесь) говорю отталкиваясь от своего опыта! найдите в инете кучу psd макетов сайтов и сделайте каждый, уверен что в процессе всплывут пробелы и не мало) вот и будет вам обучение нормальное) а то думаете что почитали книги и все знаете)) если так, то почему у вас ступр возникает))) не обманываете себя и окружающих, по меньше вопросов и больше практики! ПИШИ  КОД! ПИШИ КОД)))) удачи)

Comment: ок) спасибо) буду практиковаться)